# Using crop and creating duplicate a5 pages on one a4

Tags: crop

I often create programmes for events, and I've just been reading about the `crop` package, and was wondering, is there any way to create two identical pages from one source, and then to have the crop lines surround them?

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\dual}[1]{\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{0.45\linewidth}\centering #1\end{minipage}\hspace{0.05\linewidth}\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{0.45\linewidth}\centering #1\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}

\dual{
\blindtext[2]
}

\end{document}
```

The ideal would be for each programme (the minipages defined in `dual` in this case) to have crop marks to make it easy to guillotine the separate programmes, without the need to compile a separate file (e.g. to have to use `pdfpages`).

Comment: What about using `\fbox{}` around the `minipage`?

Comment: Feasible, but using the guillotine always ends up with lines on the final product (I'm not that great at using it); using `crop` allows for lines that don't touch the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some of [Uwe Ziegenhagen's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89139/23103), I was able to find the `zwpagelayout` package, which achieves cropmarks without clashing with pgfpages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nopageno} %loaded before zwpagelayout to avoid conflict
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage[cropmarks,a6,margins=1cm]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{ct} 

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]


\begin{document}

\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 3}{%
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\linewidth}\blindtext%
\end{minipage}\clearpage
}%
\end{document}
```

[image: preview of crop marks with pgfpages]

Although it's not *exactly* the same as `crop`, the marks don't touch the page, so it will do well.

Answer (score 3):

To create the two parallel pages from one source I recommend the `pgfpages` package. The idea behind this package is to differentiate between the one physical page and the two logical pages.

This package is also really helpful if one wants to create a `Pocketmod`, as it allow also to rotate logical pages, see http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1294

To see some more cropmarks decrease the values for `resized width` and `resized height` in the the logical page section, the settings below draw frames around each logical page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcounter{ct} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}

  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}

\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
}

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=0.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=1\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
}%
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=0.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=1.0\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{0.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

\begin{document}

\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 3}{%
\blindtext%
\clearpage}%
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfpages]

Comment: Thanks, but method doesn't really create anything different from my current setup, but using an `fbox` around the minipages. I'm really after the crop marks produced by `crop`. I'll try and include a picture of what I'm after in my post. Nice way do duplicate content though!